# First time I have ever gotten a floating point exception and I have no idea what to do

Tags: c, floating-point

I have to create a program that jumbles up numbers in a certain order, I know my code is probably not the greatest, but I have a floating point exception and I have no idea why, any help would be appreciated

```
 #define DIV 10
 long long int inputNum();
 int checkLength(long long int);
 int even(int, long long int);
 int odd(int, long long int);
 long long int calcNewNum(int, long long int);
 void print(long long int, long long int);

 int main()
 {
   long long int input = 0;
   int length = 0;
   int check = 0;
   int finalNum = 0;

   input = inputNum();
   length = checkLength(input);
   check = odd(length, input);
   finalNum = calcNewNum(length, input);
   print(input, finalNum);
   return(0);
 }

 long long int inputNum()
 {
   long long int input = 0;
   do{
   printf("Enter your non-negative integer: ");
   scanf("%lld", &input);
   if(input < 0)
   {
     printf("Error!  Non-negative integers only!!\n");
   }
   }while(input < 0);
   return(input);
 }

 int checkLength(long long int input)
 {
   int ct = 0;

   do{
   input /= DIV;
   ct++;
   }while(input != 0);

   return(ct);
 }

 int even(int length, long long int input)
 {
   int digitOne = 0;
   int digitTwo = 0;
   int i;
   int divideOne = 0;
   int firstNum = 0;
   int secondNum = 0;
   int finalNum = 0;

   digitOne = length / 2;
   digitTwo = (length / 2) + 1;

   divideOne = length - digitTwo;

   for(i = 0; i < divideOne; i++)
   {
     input /= DIV;
   }

   secondNum = input % DIV;
   input /= DIV;
   firstNum = input % DIV;

   if(firstNum < secondNum)
   {
     finalNum = firstNum;
   }
   else
   {
     finalNum = secondNum;
   }
   return(finalNum);
 }

 int odd(int length, long long int input)
 {
   int digit = 0;
   int i;
   int divide = 0;
   int midNum = 0;

   digit = length / 2;

   divide = length - digit;

   for(i = 0; i < digit; i++)
   {
     input /= DIV;
   }

   midNum = input % DIV;

   return(midNum);
 }

 long long int calcNewNum(int length, long long int input)
 {
   int finalNum = 0;
   long long int holder = 0;
   int ct = 0;
   int singleNum = 0;
   long long int temp = 0;

   holder = input;
   ct = length;

   if(input == 0)
   {
     finalNum = 0;
   }
   if(input / 10 == 0)
   {
     finalNum = input;
   }

   holder = input;

   while(holder > 0)
   {
     if(holder % 2 == 0)
     {
       singleNum = even(length, holder);
       length--;
     }
     if(holder % 2 == 1)
     {
       singleNum = odd(length, holder);
       length--;
     }
     temp = holder % (long long int)pow(DIV,ct - 1);
     holder /= pow(DIV, ct - 1);
     holder *= pow(DIV, ct - 2);
     holder += temp;
     ct--;
     finalNum += singleNum;
     printf("%lld", holder);
     if(holder != 0)
     {
       finalNum *= DIV;
     }
   }
   return(finalNum);
 } 

 void print(long long int input, long long int finalNum)
 {
   printf("Original Input: %lld", input);
   printf("Altered Number: %lld", finalNum);
 }
```

Comment: Lines 164 and 165 seem like they could be a problem. Check the result of `pow(DIV,ct-1)` for zero before using it.

Comment: Your code is asking for an input number. Which number causes crash ? I couldn't get any error on my machine. Also, maybe you give us the **exact** error you get.

Comment: Also you should include math.h and stdio.h explicitly at the beginning of the file. It compiles without with most compilers, but Clang gives some warnings.

Comment: “floating-point exception” on Intel processors means **integer** division by zero. By default, this exception is not emitted for any floating-point operation (but it is for integer division by zero).

Answer (score 2):

Greg in the comments above was right - the error happens at line 164, it's a divide by zero error when the variable ct is 0.  In that line, you're dividing by 10 to the power ct-1 which will be 10^(-1) there. So pow() returns .1 and since you cast it as long long int, the decimal is cut off and it tries to divide by 0.

Also this error seems to only occur when the sum of the digits in the input number is greater than or equal to ten.  I didn't go over the whole program to figure out why that is.  What exactly is the goal of the program?

Comment: The goal of the program is given the user input, create a new number as follows: If the number is even, find the smaller of the middle two digits and this is the first/next number in your new number. If the number is odd, take the middle number and place it as the first/next part of the new number. Remove the number that you place in the new number, and repeat the process until the original input has no number left in it. Also, not allowed to use arryas

Comment: Do you mean when the number of digits is odd or even?  That would make sense to me because a number with an even number of digits has two middle digits and a number with and odd number digits has one central digit.  Is this for an assignment or something?

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant. Sorry for not clarifying that.

Answer (score 0):

OK, as others mentioned, for an input which sum of numbers is greater than or equal to 10, at line

```
 temp = holder % (long long int)pow(DIV,ct - 1);
```

the right part of the modulo

```
(long long int)pow(DIV,ct - 1);
```

returns 0. Therefore the modulo operation overflows (divide by 0).

And by the way, it returns 0 because somehow your code reaches ct=0, that is, your are trying to calculate 10^{-1}; this corresponds to the decimal number 0.1 which is rounded to 0 in integer type.

I don't know what you're code's doing, but it has a bug :D

Answer (score 0):

Problem is here

```
 temp = holder % (long long int)pow(DIV,ct - 1);
```

Its always returning some negative value so temp will always be same as the number that you have entered. So this

```
 holder /= pow(DIV, ct - 1);
```

will always make holder as 0 and `holder += temp;` will always make holder as the number tha tyou have entered.

while(holder > 0) will always be true and it will run infinitely.

Check **pow()**. Its signature is  **double pow(double x, double y)** and you are using DIV. That could be the issue.